# Cache Optimization Theory

Tags: c++, performance, caching, optimization

I am thinking about heavy memory cache optimization and like to have some feedback.
Consider this example:

```
class example
    {
        float phase1;
        float phaseInc;
        float factor;
    public:
        void process(float* buffer,unsigned int iSamples)//<-high prio audio thread
        {
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iSamples; i++)// mostly iSamples is 32
            {
                phase1 += phaseInc;
                float f1 = sinf(phase1);//<-sinf is just an example!            
                buffer[i] = f1*factor;
            }
        }
    };
```

optimization idea:

```
 void example::process(float* buffer,unsigned int iSamples)
    {
        float stackMemory[3];// should fit in L1 
        memcpy(stackMemory,&phase1,sizeof(float)*3);// get all memory at once
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iSamples; i++)
        {
            stackMemory[0] += stackMemory[1];
            float f1 = sinf(stackMemory[0]);
            buffer[i] = f1*stackMemory[2];
        }
        memcpy(&phase1,stackMemory,sizeof(float)*1);// write back only changed mameory 
    }
```

Note that the real sample loop will contain thousands of operations.
So the stackMemory can become quite big. 
I think it will be not more then 32kb (are there any smaller L1's out there ?).

Does the order of the used variables in this stackmemory matter ?
I hope not, because i'd like to order them so that i can reduce the writeback size.
Or does the L1 cache have the same cachline behaviour that RAM has ?

I have the feeling that i am somehow doing what prefetch is made for, but all i read about prefetch is relative vague about how to use it efficently. Try and error is not an option with 5000+ lines of code.

Code will run on Win,Mac and iOS.
Any ARM<->Intel issues to expect ?

Is it possible that this kind optimization is useless since all memory is accessed and transferred to L1 on the first iteration of the loop anyway ?

Thanks for any hints and ideas.

Comment: Are you suggesting to optimize the mem access of the 3 member variables? They'll get fetched together anyhow (and probably within the same access), and filled to the cache in the process. You're just creating one additional copy that would take extra space on the cache (assuming the compiler can't eliminate this unnecessary duplication).

Comment: Try to move `phase1 += phaseInc;` out of the loop (the compiler might already be doing this). It turns into `phase1 += phaseInc*iSamples;`

Comment: It seems premature optimization to me. Even if the only function you call in the loop is `sinf`, it will be more expensive than anything else in one iteration of the loop. And you write *"Note that the real sample loop will contain thousands of operations."* which further confirms that **you are optimizing the wrong thing.** Reduce the work inside the loop and forget about the caching if you want your loop to be faster.

Comment: The example should just show how i intend to optimize. The real loop will contain THOUSANDS line of (already optimized)code. Unfortunaly in the audio DSP world you have a lot of data dependency, so taking code out of the loop is no possible.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought there was a good chance that the second one could be slower as a result of additional memory access and instructions required for `memcpy`, while the first could simply work directly with these three class members already loaded into registers.

Nevertheless, I tried fiddling with the code in GCC 5.2 with both `-O2` and `-O3` and found that, no matter what I tried, I got identical assembly instructions for both. This is pretty amazing considering all the extra conceptual work that `memcpy` typically has to do that apparently got squashed away to zilch.

The one case I can think of where your second version might be faster in some scenario, on some compiler, is if the aliasing involved to access `this->data_member` interfered with an optimization and caused redundant loads and stores to/from registers.

It would have nothing to do with the L1 cache in that case and everything to do with register allocation on the compiler side. Caches are largely irrelevant here when you're loading the same memory (member variables) regardless for a contiguous chunk of data, it has entirely to do with registers. Nevertheless, I couldn't find a single scenario where I could cause that to happen where the compiler did a worse job with one over the other -- every case I tested yielded identical results. In a sufficiently complex real world case, perhaps there might be a difference.

Then again, in such a case, it should be on the safer side to simply do:

```
 void process(float* buffer,unsigned int iSamples)
 {
     const float pi = phaseInc;
     const float p1 = phase1;
     const float fact = factor;
     for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iSamples; i++)
     {
         phase1 += pi;
         float f1 = sinf(p1);
         buffer[i] = f1*fact;
     }
 }
```

There's no need to jump through hoops with `memcpy` to store the results into an array and back. That puts additional strain on the optimizer even if, in my findings, the optimizer managed to eliminate the overhead typically associated.

I realize your example is simplified, but there should not be a need to reduce the structure down to such a primitive array no matter how many data members you're dealing with (unless such an array actually is the most convenient representation). From a performance standpoint, a compiler will have an "easier" time (even if optimizers today are pretty amazing and can handle this) optimizing if you just use local variables instead of an array to which you `memcpy` aggregate data members in and out.